# Looking for an English term or expression that describes a man who has been charmed and subjugated by a woman

Tags: single-word-requests

Like, a word or term for the resultant state of a man who has been completely charmed by a woman and brought under her control, or even a term for the act wherein a woman renders a man in such a state. Is there anything at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many words or phrases that have overtones of being dominated rather than charmed but I can only suggest three that have a more positive feeling of being delightfully charmed:

> ***bewitched***
>
> from *bewitch* = to attract or interest someone a lot so that you have the power to influence them
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bewitch)

> ***captivated***
>
> from
> *captivate* = to hold the attention of someone by being extremely interesting, exciting, charming, or attractive
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/captivate)

> ***enchanted*** = made to feel delightfully pleased or charmed; placed under or as if under a magic spell
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enchanted)

Of these three I like *captivated* because it lacks the connotations of magic that sometimes accompany *enchanted* or *bewitched*

The woman *enchants*, *bewitches* or *captivates*.

Answer (score 1):

A vamp is a

> *a woman who uses her charm or wiles to seduce and exploit men.*
> ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vamped))

"Vamped", may well describe what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "he has become his wife's **puppet**".  Not specific for the situation described in the OP, a puppet refers to "anyone whose behavior is determined by the will of others". [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/puppet#:%7E:text=(p%C5%ADp%E2%80%B2%C4%ADt),strings%20or%20wires%3B%20a%20marionette.)

or

- He has become **"a meek"** or **"submissive husband"**.

> - [meek](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/meek) - easily imposed on; submissive.

Answer (score 0):

Some more positive words could be:

- wooed
- enamored
- swept off his feet

Others with some negative undertones:

- sugaring

Comment: Neither of the first two is specifically about a man who has been charmed by a woman.